# Get primefaces inputtext value with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces

I have following code

```
<h:form id="calcForm">
  <h:panelGrid columns="3" styleClass="panelGridNoBorder">
    <p:inputText id="value" />
    <p:commandButton value="calculate " onclick="calc()" />
  </h:panelGrid>
  <script>
    function calc() {
      var value = $("#value").val();
      console.log(value);
      alert(value);
    }
  </script>
</h:form>
```

I want press calculate button and show alert with value from inputtext. But I get `undefine`. I see that inputtext id is `calcForm:value`. How can I get inputtext value?

EDIT:
in code

```
<p:inputText id="value" />
```

in browser

```
<input id="calcForm:value" name="calcForm:value" type="text" maxlength="18" style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: 2.4em;" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly  following will solve your issue

```
var value = $("#calcForm\\:value").val()
```

```js
function calc() {
  var value = $("#calcForm\\:value").val();
  console.log(value);
  alert(value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="calcForm:value" name="calcForm:value" type="text" maxlength="18" style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: 2.4em;" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
<button onclick="calc()">Calculate</button>
```

Comment: inputText id="value" but in browser in html id is calcForm:value. I tried $("#value").val(); $("#calcForm").find("#value").val();

Comment: Now not show undefine but value is empty. alert("hz" + value); show only hz

Comment: Anything in the text box.? pls run the snippet it will work

Comment: I use primefaces.  Maby primefaces work not curectly.........var value = document.getElementById('calcForm:value').innerHTML; not work too